# For Loop Iteration and Algorithm Can Someone help me?

Tags: for-loop

Can Someone help me?
I want to Iterate the Value of 'n' in This Manner. in any Language.
please explain the Concept.

```
if n = 5
sum = (5x5)+(4x4)-(3x3)+(2x2)-(1x1)

sum = 35;
```

I want to display like that value.

but it should iterate in this Manner

```
(nxn)+(n-1xn-1)-(n-2xn-2)+(n-3xn-3)-(n-4xn-4)+...;
```

When `n-x==1` that time the iteration should get stop and Value should be printed.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i+){
   sum=0
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
      sum = sum+(j*j);
      if(j<=i){
         print(sum);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are multiple languages tagged? May you share a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Explain this basic programming concept” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  Is the Answer which i got.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int limit;
    int sumOfSquare = 0;
    cin>>limit;
    
    sumOfSquare= limit*limit;
    for(int num = 1; num<limit; num++)
    {
        if(limit%2==0){
            if(num%2==0)
            sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare - (num * num);
            else
            sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare + (num * num);
        }else{
            if(num%2==0)
            sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare + (num * num);
            else
            sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare - (num * num);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Output of " << limit << " is " << sumOfSquare;
    return 0;
}
```